# Хранимая процедура добавления нового пользователя

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_InsertUsers
@Email NVARCHAR(30) ,
@Password NVARCHAR(20),
@Nickname NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF EXISTS(SELECT UsersTable.Email, UsersTable.Login FROM UsersTable     WHERE UsersTable.Email = @Email or UsersTable.Login = @Nickname) --check email
   BEGIN
          SELECT -1 AS FALSE
   END

   ELSE
   BEGIN
          INSERT INTO UsersTable(Email, Pass, Login, Data_reg)
          VALUES
          (@Email, @Password, @Nickname, GETDATE())
          SELECT 1 AS TRUE
   END                 
END
```

Сама процедура работает без проблем и не дает создавать нового пользователя, если логин или пароль уже есть в базе.

Но проблема в том, что не получается правильно применить ее из программы, вроде делаю все правильно.

```
var regInfo = this.mydb.SP_InsertUsers(model.Email, model.Password, model.Login).ToList();    
if (regInfo != null && regInfo.Count() != -1)
{
    mydb.SaveChanges();
    TempData["message"] = string.Format("Новая учетная запись \"{0}\" успешно создана!", model.Login.ToLower());
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

}
else
{
    TempData["message_error"] = string.Format("Такой логин или e-mail уже кем-то используется");
}
```

Как правильно выполнять условие проверки? У меня сейчас при вводе любых значений regInfo.Count() принимает значение равное 1, и поэтому даже при вводе неправильных значений в else не заходит вообще

Comment: А с чего Вы решили, что результат SELECT в процедуре будет доступен через свойство Count()? Вне зависимости от того, КАКОЕ значение возвращается, Вам всегда возвращается ОДНО значение - что Вы и наблюдаете...

Comment: А какие результаты из процедуры доступны через свойства c#?

Comment: вариантов масса. Ваш вариант нужно правильно применить. Как сказал Akina, у вас всегда возвращается одна строка, поэтому проверять надо не количество строк, а их содержимое. Другой вариант - использовать out-параметр в процедуре и проверять его значение после выполнения процедуры. Кроме этого сама процедура может возвращать произвольное целочисленное значение через RETURN, этим тоже можно воспользоваться. Можно выполнить RAISERROR и ловить его в коде. В общем есть из чего выбрать, и все это доступно в C# стандартными средствами.

Comment: а чтобы заработал ваш текущий вариант просто уберите "SELECT -1 AS FALSE" из процедуры совсем и переверните условие в IF

Comment: Перевернуть в if? Не понял

Comment: @SOFL условие в IF переверните на противоположное, чтобы код из Else выполнялся в основном блоке If, а блок Else будет не нужен в коде процедуры. Но это не красивое решение, так заглушка, которую нужно заменить на нормальное

Comment: Пробую сейчас вариант Александра, но проблема возникла. Учитывая то, что я использую локальную базу у меня проблемы с подключением

Comment: пробую разные вариации такого подключения ("data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=NewMainDBForCRUD;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");

Comment: и каждый раз при дебаге зависает на методе open(), думаю не понимает такую строку подключения

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55417/discussion-between-rdorn-and-sofl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дико извиняюсь, у меня нет сейчас возможностей для тестирования, но вот стартовая точка для решения Вашей проблемы на стороне клиента, если конечно хранимая процедура делает, то что Вы задумали:

```
        int result = 0;
        SqlConnection con;
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertUsers", con)); //Нужно уточнить, возможно что команда должна выглядить так  "Execute SP_InsertUsers(@Email, @Password, @Nickname)"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strEmail;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strPassword;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nickname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strNickname;

            con.Open();
            object res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();


            if (res != null)
            {
                result=System.Convert.ToInt16(res);
            }


        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            //Обработка исключения .....
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        if( result==1)
        {
            //Обработка успешного добавления
        }
        else
        {
            //Обработка когда добавить не смогли
        }
```

Я думаю, что идея ясна, ну что касается возможных ошибок в синтаксисе и уточнения командной строки, то я уверен, что это для Вас не проблема

Comment: Да, проблема только в клиенте. ХП отрабатывается четко

Comment: Тогда попробуйте напрямую использовать object res = cmd.ExecuteScalar(), по схеме, которую я предожил. Все должно заработать. Единственное я сейчас не помню и мне негде в данный момент посмотреть, нужно ли в командной строке при создании команды указывать список параметров и писать "EXEC". Это легко проверить экспериментально. У Вас не должно возникнуть проблем.

Comment: Я думаю переписать ХП, чтобы она к примеру не поле с числом возвращала как сейчас, а допустим RETURN 0 в случае если запись есть

Comment: Просто проблема возникает тогда, когда нужно каким-то образом в коде извлечь то, что ХП возвращает

Comment: То, что я Вам предложил, это самый надежный и быстрый способ извлечь скалярный результат работы хранимой процедуры.

Comment: Он ведь только со строкой будет работать? В том плане, только если ХП возвращает SELECT

Comment: С любым запросом и хранимой процедурой, которые возвращают скалярный результат. Например new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UsersTable", con))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55413/discussion-between-sofl-and--).

Comment: Согласен идти в чат, но уже утром, у меня закончился рабочий день. Вечер - время для тенниса и секса :)